# Mysterious stackoverflow in function call?

Tags: function, lua, stack-overflow

I'm creating a Lua program and I tried to use something like inheritance, but I got a stack overflow when I called the super of the function.

```
function Parent()
    local self = {}

    self.println = function(text) print(text) end
    return self
end


function Child()
    local super = Parent()
    local this = {}

    this.println = function(text)
        super.println(text) -- According to the debugger, here is the problem.
        print("Child")
    end

    for k, v in pairs(this) do
        super[k] = v
    end

    return this
end

local a = Child()
a.println("Hello!")
```

I know there are other ways to do this, but I **must** use this kind of "OOP". Can anyone recommend me anything?

Comment: There's a much easier form of OOP if you use __index field of a metatable.

Comment: I know, but I heard that it's faster and allows me to use private variables. It seems like I'll have to stay with metatables. :/

Comment: Metatables are probably faster then any other form of OOP, and also open up far more opportunities for object-oriented things.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is with the loop that makes all println functions be the same println function that redirects the call to another printnl function, which is actually the same print function, creating a loop.

```
for k, v in pairs(this) do
    super[k] = v
end
```

Removing that loop will make the code work, but I am not sure if this makes it behave as you wanted.
Maybe you should take a look at lua metatables if you want to inherit methods.

Comment: Works, but I have to re-declare the functions in the Child class and call the super function to make the "inherited" functions work and that is not a fancy approach.

Answer (score 1):

That `for k, v in pairs(this) do` loop seems backwards to me.

You are pushing the `this` copies of the functions into the `super` table (overwriting the ones that are already there).

So you push `this.println` into `super` and then call `super.println` inside it and you end up calling yourself repeatedly.

Did you mean to do that the other way around? Copy the `super` functions into `this`? Or what was the point with that loop in the first place?

Comment: You are right. I wanted to copy the functions of Parent into Child to be accessible from the "a" variable.

Comment: Right, except you really don't want that. You want them to be looked up *in* Parent when they aren't in *Child* and that's what `__index` in the metatable is for the way warspyking suggests. (And I have no idea what your response comment to them was supposed to mean and it doesn't seem to make much sense.)